# Wamp & Mandrill: "error setting certificate verify locations"

Tags: php, wamp, ssl-certificate, wampserver, mandrill

I'm trying to test our Mandrill API from my localhost (on Windows). It seems like I need to configure a "local issuer certificate". So, I downloaded http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and saved it in my document root (c:\wamp\www). Then, in my php.ini file, I configured this: `curl.cainfo = "/cacert.pem"`.

When I run the sample code for Mandrill, I get the following error:

> A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_HttpError - API call to
>   messages/send failed: error setting certificate verify locations:
>   CAfile: cacert.pem CApath: none

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen others post about this with WampServer; though I cannot offer the reason or a real solution, if you're just testing on your localhost have you considered just turning off cURL's SSL verification?

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: Good answer. Actually, disabling only CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER was enough.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the @LeonardChallis answer if you're struggling with Google APIs on this one then adding the following to vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php and the create function will also fix it:

`$conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 0;`

`$conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = 0;`